How has the anatomy of a system call changed over iterations of the Linux kernel?
I've been reading Anatomy of a system call, part 1 and trying to get the full picture of what actions occur when a syscall instruction is issued. From what I do understand:

The user program readies appropriate registers and issues syscall instruction
The machine is switched to kernel mode and jumps to the system_call routine implemented in /arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S (This address is written to the MSR_LSTAR register upon kernel initialization).
The system_call routine jumps to the appropriate syscall handler function, as specified by RAX
The return value is placed in RAX, and somehow the machine switches back to user-mode (The article didn't specify this procedure).

My main gripe is that the system_call entry point is implemented in /arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S, which doesn't exist in later versions of Linux, eg Linux 6.10.10. How should learners keep up-to-date with the true anatomy of a syscall? If the answer is "Figure it out yourself", what would be a good starting point?

They just moved it to a different directory, arch/x86/entry.  The basic principles haven't changed.
